# html desplaying a list of books in html as a table

Tags: html, list, spring-boot

I am new to all of this, I am using spring boot to make a simple book list web MVC app, I amapped the books to objects from an xml file and now I am trying to display them but I am not able to, here is my controller function:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/all", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String getAllBooks(Model model) {
    List<Book> books = bookService.getAllBooks();
    model.addAttribute("listBooks", books);
    return "books";
}
```

and this is the function getAllBooks in BookServiceImp.java:

```
  public List<Book> getAllBooks() {
    return !CollectionUtils.isEmpty(books) ? books : new ArrayList<>();
}

public List<Book> getAllAvailaBooks() {
    return !CollectionUtils.isEmpty(books)
            ? books.stream().filter(book -> !book.isBorrowed()).collect(Collectors.toList())
            : new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and here is my books.html file: https://pastebin.com/WkfmruEc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was silly and I didn't notice that I had user instead of boo in the html file.